# React typescript is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, types

I am using typescript in a react project.

I am getting the following error.

> Argument of type '{ teams: { home: { name: string; }; away: {
>   name: string; }; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'Fixtures[] | (() => Fixture[])'.

My type definitions and use in a react component are below.

```
type Team = {
    name: 'Liverpool' | 'Man Utd';
};

type Fixtures = {
    teams: {
        home: {
            name: Team;
        },
        away: {
            name: Team;
        },
        winner: Team;
    };
};

const initialFixtures = [
    {
        teams: {
            home: {
                name: 'Liverpool',
            },
            away: {
                name: 'Man Utd',
            },
        },
        winner: 'Liverpool',
    },
];
```

I am then using this in my React component like below but

```
// Error is in `initial fixtures`
const [fixtures, updateFixtures] = useState<Fixtures[]>(initialFixtures);
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? I can't see where it is inferring it to be a string when I have said it is a `Team`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not related to react, its related to how Typescript infers string literal types. Typescript will not infer string literal types unless it has a reason to do so.

In this case `initialFixtures` is untyped. So typescript has no reason to infer `name` as `'Liverpool' | 'Man Utd'` so it infers it as `string`. When you later try to assign `initialFixtures` with its inferred type to `Fixture[]` the assignment fails (since `string` is not assignable to `Team`):

```
type Team =  'Liverpool' | 'Man Utd';

type Fixtures = {
    teams: {
        home: {
            name: Team;
        },
        away: {
            name: Team;
        },
    };
    winner: Team;
};

const initialFixtures= [
    {
        teams: {
            home: {
                name: 'Liverpool',
            },
            away: {
                name: 'Man Utd',
            },
        },
        winner: 'Liverpool',
    },
];
let o: Fixtures[] = initialFixtures; // error here 
// Type '{ teams: { home: { name: string; }; away: { name: string; }; }; winner: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Fixtures[]'.
```

The simple solution is to type `initialFixtures` and not ask the compiler to infer anything and just check the object literal):

```
const initialFixtures: Fixtures[]= [
    {
        teams: {
            home: {
                name: 'Liverpool',
            },
            away: {
                name: 'Man Utd',
            },
        },
        winner: 'Liverpool',
    },
];
let o: Fixtures[] = initialFixtures; //ok
```

Comment: that is the solution :-D

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, the shape of your data isn't matching up:

Notice you are using 'term' instead of 'away' in your initialFixtures array, and then 'away' instead of 'name'. So you shapes are not matching up. It may help to declare your initialFixtures const as a Fixtures[] as typescript will probably not implicitly realise that.

It looks like useState is a polymorphic function that takes an array of the assigned type Fixtures or a callback that returns the Fixtures[] type.

So as far as I can tell:

```
term: {
  away: 'Man Utd',
},
```

Should be

```
away: {
  name: 'Man Utd'
}
```

Comment: apologies, I amended the question a bit to use different variable names. Updated now

Answer (score 0):

`type Team = 'Liverpool' | 'Man Utd';`

Reason is typescript thinks that your structure should be:

```
            home: {
                name: {
                   name: 'Liverpool'
                }
            },
            away: {
                name: {
                   name: 'Man Utd'
                }
            },
```

Alternatively you could keep the team type the same but change the Fixtures type to:

```
type Fixtures = {
    teams: {
        home: Team;
        away: Team;
        winner: Team;
    };
};
```

Keep in mind that winner will be an object of {name: 'Teamname'} Not a string of the team name